# How to get the parent div id in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to get the parent div id (the div class is called "col-sm-2") when selecting each option in HTML "select" tag in each div. But it always gives only the div id of latest added product at "id" alert. For example if the id of my last added product is "7", it always gives "7" as the alert.

Here is my PHP code for getting the product id.

```
$jsql_ae7 = mysql_query("select request_list.product_id from request_list where request_list.product_id='{$jrowa2['id']}' and request_list.email='$visit_email'") or die(mysql_error());
$jfeta7 = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsql_ae7);
```

Here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="col-sm-2" id="<?php echo $jfeta7['product_id']; ?>">
    <select id="formats_id" name="aformats" onchange="showFormat(this);">
        <option value="<?php echo $jrowa2['formats']; ?>"><?php echo $jrowa2['formats']; ?></option>
            <?php foreach($formats3 as $v3){  ?>
                <?php if($v3 !== $jrowa2['formats']) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $v3; ?>"><?php echo $v3; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>          
            <?php } ?>

    </select>
</div>
```

Here is my javaScript code.

```
var showFormat = function(dd) {
    var format_value = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;
    var scriptTags = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    var id = scriptTags[scriptTags.length - 1].parentNode.id;
    alert(id);        
};
```

Comment: check my answer using javascript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use [**each**](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('select').each(function() {
   alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You coild get the id property of the immediate container div using `closest()` :

```
$('select').on('change',function() {
   alert($(this).closest('div').prop('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
var showFormat = function(dd) {
     var format_value = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;
    var scriptTags = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    var parent = scriptTags[scriptTags.length - 1].parentNode;
    alert(parent.getAttribute('id'));        
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqdmmroh/)

```
$('#formats_id').change(function(){

    alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First we will start with making the selection:

```
$('select').each(function() {
   var selectField = $(this); // this will point to select element
});
```

There are two ways:

1. This will take direct parent of select

   selectField.parent().attr('id');
2. This will select first ancestor that is a div with class 'my-class':

   selectField.closest('div.my-class').attr('id');

Both work, but differ in deep of search:)